# Joomla 1.5. Text over image doesn't work

Tags: php, image, text, joomla, imagettftext

I'm useing Joomla 1.5. I have the script for create image with text over It, but It doesn't work for me:

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = "ARIAL.TFF";

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. I found many examples in google, I used It, but always the same. [image: error]
This error in english means: `Image "http://juokoera.lt/a.php" can't be shown, because It have problems (errors)`.

I found in google, that can be fault by my hosting, I changed It, but the same problem. Help me, please if you can. Thank you very much.

**UPDATED:**
I got the same error when, code looks like:

```
dasfasdf
dfas

<?php 
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);
$text = 'Testing...';
$font = "ARIAL.TTF";
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im); ?>
```

How can I use additional text in the same php?

Comment: My guess is that you do not have "ARIAL.TFF" available. Make sure it does exist. After commenting that line your code produces image without any text, of course.

Comment: Also, a common mistake is to have any output before the code. I.e. even a new line or a space character before image generating PHP code will result in this error.

Comment: @varnie The missing font file reference should not produce this error just leave the image blank w/o text.

Comment: ARIAL.TFF is placed in .../public_html/ folder maybe i need to write path to ttf like `$font = "/public_html/ARIAL.TFF";` ? And this is all my a.php file, nothing more inside It.

Comment: I updated my post with 1 more code which return the same error for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
$font = "ARIAL.TFF";
```

in fact, on your server a file named "ARIAL.TFF" doesn't exist, the font extension you are looking for is TTF, not TFF, and in fact "ARIAL.TTF" on your server exists and i just downloaded it, correct that line to:

```
$font = "ARIAL.TTF";
```

After that, you should be able to write text on your image

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**

After question update, i noticed that an header is sent after printing out some text.

Nothing has to be printed out before the `header()` function, in order for headers to be correctly sent.

In the [PHP manual>header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) it is the first thing that is explained:

`Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.`

Comment: OMG, stupid mistake... Always I though that It is TFF not TTF... Thank you very much, that solved my problem.

Comment: I don't understand why my code doesn't work when I use the same code Just add some text before It?

Comment: @user2055113 Now i see your a.php working well... Where is the problem?

Comment: here, look at this juokoera.lt/1b.php

Comment: I just saw the update, when you send a header, **nothing** has to be printed out before the header. From [PHP manual>header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php): `Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.`